# ng-mousover to select ONLY the hovered element not all elements - using ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, mouseover, onmouseover

I need to add and remove a class to an element on mouseover. The method below adds and removes classes from all elements with classname .blogOverlay and .newOverlay.

I need it to add/remove the class ONLY on the element that is being hovered over.

JS:

```
$scope.showReadMore = function(){
  $('.blogOverlay').addClass("hidden");
  $('.newOverlay').removeClass('hidden');
}
$scope.hideReadmore = function(){
  $('.blogOverlay').removeClass("hidden");
  $('.newOverlay').addClass('hidden');
}
```

HTML:

```
  <div ng-if="!post.firstFeatured" class="col-sm-10 blog-content blogPreview" >
                            <a ng-click="goToPostDetail(post, $index)" >
                              <img class="img-responsive img-blog" ng-src="{{ post.fields.image.fields.file.url }}" width="100%" alt=""  />
                              <div class="blogOverlay" ng-mouseover="showReadMore()" ng-mouseleave="hideReadmore()">
                                  <h2>{{ post.fields.title }}</h2>
                              </div>

                              <div class="newOverlay hidden" ng-mouseover="showReadMore()" ng-mouseleave="hideReadmore()">
                                  <h2>{{ post.fields.title }}</h2>
                                  <h3>{{post.fields.date}}</h3>
                                  <a class="btn btn-primary readmore" ng-click="goToPostDetail(post, $index)">Read More</a>
                              </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
```

Comment: it seems that you are using jquery ? why is it so?

Comment: @Aravind open to other suggestions

Comment: update your css classes ? and json values

Comment: check my answer below. Let me know if u need further help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use jquery. Just use **ng-class** and add a condition to show or hide that class to your post. Se snipped how content is shown or hidden with the hidden class according to property `post.readMore` in the controller

```js
angular.module('myapp', [])
  .controller('foo', function($scope) {

    $scope.post = {
      readMore: true,
      fields: {
        title: 'The post title',
        date: new Date()
      }
    }

    $scope.showReadMore = function(post) {
      post.readMore = true;
    }
    $scope.hideReadmore = function(post) {
      post.readMore = false;
    }


  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

  <style type="text/css">
    .hidden {
      display: none;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body ng-app="myapp">
  <div ng-controller="foo">

    <div ng-if="!post.firstFeatured" class="col-sm-10 blog-content blogPreview" style="max-width: 400px">
      <a ng-click="goToPostDetail(post, $index)">
        <img class="img-responsive img-blog" ng-src="{{ post.fields.image.fields.file.url }}" width="100%" alt="" />

        <div class="blogOverlay" ng-class="{'hidden' : !post.readMore}" ng-mouseover="showReadMore(post)" ng-mouseleave="hideReadmore(post)">
          <h2>{{ post.fields.title }}</h2>
        </div>

        <div class="newOverlay" ng-class="{'hidden' : post.readMore}" ng-mouseleave="showReadMore(post)" ng-mouseover="hideReadmore(post)">
          <h2>{{ post.fields.title }}</h2>
          <h3>{{post.fields.date}}</h3>
          <a class="btn btn-primary readmore" ng-click="goToPostDetail(post, $index)">Read More</a>
        </div>

      </a>
    </div>

  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you!! It's working. Do you mind explaining what the purpose of `         fields: {
           title: 'The post title',
           date: new Date()
         }`

Comment: No specific purpose. Just to fill out those attributes you just put in your code (in the question) and give you the opportunity to see how these properties of *post* were shown and hidden on mouseover and mouseleave :)

Answer (score 0):

give class name something like `class="blogOverlay_{{$index}}"` and then pass `$index` to JavaScript like `showReadMore($index)`

This way Your class names are unique and they will change for only `index` you want to change

Comment: What is the easiest way to avoid "blogOverlay_{{$index}}" effecting the css that is already in place for blogOverlay

Comment: You can create new class that has no associated style in css. Just to get that unquely. Add then use it as jquery selectoe for adding/removing hidden class

Comment: getting "unrecognized expression $index"

Answer (score 0):

You need not complicate much Check out the below css and live plunker

```
.blue{
  
  background-color:blue;
}
.red{
  
  background-color:red;
}
.blue:hover
{
  
  background-color:yellow;
  visibility:hidden
}
```

[PLUNKER DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/7RRlxmvTnggyw2LnOzPq?p=preview)

Update 1 : Hides and shows

Comment: I understand how this is working, but the issue that I'm having is adding and removing classes.

Comment: why is it u want to add or remove a class?

Comment: I need to remove class hidden on the div with content that i need to display. and add class hidden to the div with the content that i'd like to hide. your plunked is changing background color

Comment: I would suggest you to go with this, why to write methods and use jquery when it is actually not needed!! give me your css styles .